# Unterschied zwischen "Lebensinhalt" und "Lebenssinn"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "Lebensinhalt" und "Lebenssinn"?

In einem Artikel geht es um Sport für Leute mit Behinderungen. Da waren die beide Wörter als Synonyme benutzt. Meiner Meinung nach war das falsch: Sport kann ein Lebensinhalt werded, aber kein Lebenssinn.

Comment: Please consider to elaborate you question (with an [edit]) to make answers other than "yes" possible. What did your dictionaries say? Did you find any possibilities you may have issues with? As it stands now people likely will close it. See http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Comment: Maybe migrate this question to philosophy.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lebensinhalt is closer to Lebensaufgabe or Berufung / Beruf.

It is what is fulfilling to you. It is filling you up making you whole. It is the what.

The Sinn is the reason why. It's the why.

So Inhalt is the what you do that you do in order to fulfill your destiny and the Sinn is the why you do what you do in order to fulfill your destiny or fill your life up with content (Inhalt) or give your life meaning (Sinn).

Answer (score 1):

Im Zweifelsfall einen philosophischen ...

Lebensinhalt: was im Leben passierte. Stark vereinfacht die "vita" oder eben **wie** man sein leben **verbracht** hat

Lebenssinn: "meaning of life" oder **was** das Leben einem selbst und/oder anderen **gebracht** hat.

Comment: Gar nicht so phliosophisch: ein großer Teil meines Lebensinhalts ist meine Arbeit (ich verbringe 8 Stunden pro Werktag da), aber das ist nicht mein Lebenssinn.